# Feedback and possible better method for my get and post requests in C# using httpclient

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpclient, system.net.httpwebrequest

A bit bothered by how I am doing this, and wanted some feedback on a better way.

Here is some code I wrote to post to a website, I will also show the get request as well.

So assuming you don't need to see when we construct the HttpClient, CookieContainer, and ClientHandler here is the code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ListLogin = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(); //key value pair is the input name and then the input value to be used
ListLogin = AddToList("userid", "someUser", ListLogin);
ListLogin = AddToList("passwd", "somePassword", ListLogin);
ListLogin = AddToList("domain", "whoCares", ListLogin);
ListLogin = AddToList("destinationURL", "/", ListLogin);
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> QueryLogin = GetEnumerable(ListLogin);

PostRequest("URL.com", QueryLogin);
```

So the above is building the key value pair for what the server will expect. Then using the methods to construct the request.

**I will also show the AddToList method:**

```
  public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AddToList(string 
         strInput1, string strInput2, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> 
        ListInput)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> NewList = ListInput;
    NewList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(strInput1, strInput2));
    return NewList;
}
```

**Here is also the getEnumerable method:**

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerable(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ListInput)
            {
                IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queriesNew = ListInput;
                return queriesNew;
            }
```

**Finally the post and get request methods:**

```
      async static void PostRequest(string strUrl,
      IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queries)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(strUrl);
    cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri);
    HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queries);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(strUrl, q);

    HttpContent content = response.Content;
    string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Console.WriteLine(myContent);
    // Console.WriteLine(response);

    IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies =
    response.Dispose();

}

async static Task<String> GetRequest(string strUrl)
{

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(strUrl);
    HttpContent content = response.Content;  //content of the response 
    string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(myContent);
    response.Dispose();  //dispose of the response
    return myContent;

}
```

Just looking for some constructive criticism on my approach.When I am typing new get and post requests, it just feel repetitive, and I was under the impression usually if it feels repetitive, there might be a better way.And then to make this a bit of a two part question, the PostRequest and GetRequest methods.I think it would be better to put that into its own class so its reusable in other solutions/projects? Yay/nay?

A thank you in advance.

Comment: Your get & add methods are completely useless.

Comment: Do not use `async void`.

Comment: @mikecmr Placing your request methods in a separate class would be beneficial, especially if you need to re-use them in another project. Also, as SLaks mentioned, you should return a `Task` in an `async void method`, so instead of `async void` do `async Task`

Comment: @RyanWilson going to give that a try. So aside from that, this is a pretty standard way to do this type of action?

Comment: @MikeCMR As far as I know this seems correct. If you wanted to make this even more re-useable, you could build your own API which handles sending the requests to the other APIs, then you could just call your custom API from any project.

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks man! As far as that goes, do you have any materials I could read up on?

Comment: @MikeCMR Here is a getting started article off of Microsoft's Documentation for creating an API with dotnet core: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1). I would start there and go through that first. Then if you need more help, you can always post new questions here, there are a lot of documents and tutorials out there for building an API.

Comment: @RyanWilson perfect, appreciate the advice. Will do!

Comment: @MikeCMR Happy coding, I am voting to close this post as I don't think you are going to get any concrete answer(s).

Comment: @RyanWilson agreed. And apologize for hitting you up again with another ?. But when I remove the void from that method with the async keyword, it requests I put an await on the method call in the main, but then it gets upset because the main doesn't have the async keyword on it. But I thought (in this comments string) async and void shouldnt really be together?

Comment: @MikeCMR When calling the method in `main`, if you can't make `main` `async Task` you can call your method and chain it with `.Result()` and it will treat it like a synchronous method call. And no worries about asking another question.

Comment: @RyanWilson reading on that now. So wouldn't you need to always use the result()? Because in a console app we have our main (start of the program), so if you want to use async at all, this would always be necessary, no?

Comment: If the method you call an asyncronous method from is not async then yes. As of C# 7.1 you can use the asynchronous main method please see here (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/12/08/async-main-is-available-but-hidden/)